# How to compute $\int\tfrac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm dx$ without substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\,\mathrm dx$$

For this above problem, I tried adding and subtracting a $e^x$ to the numerator and proceeded. I did end up with an answer. I also tried to solve this question by taking $e^{x/2}$ common from both numerator and the denominator.

$$\int\frac{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}\mathrm dx$$

Once I've taken $e^{x/2}$ out from the denominator and the numerator, I thought of applying this property:
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\, \mathrm dx = \ln |f(x)|+C$$
But I am unable to manipulate my obtained expression using this property.

Comment: I guess it's hard to do without substitution. Try $t = e^{x}$

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why you are looking for an answer that doesn't use substitution? Integration by substitution is just the chain rule from differentiation, why not allow that to be used?

Comment: this problem can be solved with ease by using substitution. But i wanna know how to manipulate this one using algebra.

Comment: @bhuvanesh if you allow complex numbers, then try $$\frac{e^{x}+1}{e^{x}-1}=\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=i\cot\left(\frac{ix}{2}\right)$$

Comment: "Suppose $t=x/2$": no, you are breaking your own rule !

Comment: read the note at the end

Comment: i tried to type e^(x/2) but i am not really used to typing in this page. so, yeah..

Comment: Mh, what is a change of variable and what is a clean rewrite ? You are tricking us.

Comment: aight, let me rewrite the question to avoid confusion

Comment: You should recognize that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator, to a constant factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use your approach:
$I=\int\frac{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}\mathrm dx=2 \int\frac{\frac{e^{x/2}}{2}+\frac{e^{-x/2}}{2}}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}\mathrm dx =2 \int\frac{(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})'}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}\mathrm dx =2\ln|e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}|+c$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}+\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}.$$

Both terms are of the form $\frac{f'}f$ and you can integrate straight away, giving

$$\log|(e^x-1)(1-e^{-x})|.$$

---

Alternatively,

$$\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}=\frac{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}=2\frac{(e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2})'}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}\to 2\log|e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}|.$$

---

It is questionable whether this is truly "without substitution", because implicitly you are doing

$$\int\frac{f'}{f}dx=\int\frac{df}f.$$

Comment: i very well understood your approach. Can you help me in analyzing my approach?

Comment: @bhuvanesh: you are stuck with your approach, what do you want me to analyze ?

Comment: look, i took e^(x/2) out from both the numerator and the denominator. Now, by observing carefully, i am able to see that if i multiple 1/2 to my numerator, my numerator will then become the derivative of my denominator. But im not getting the answer..

Comment: @bhuvanesh: I have added a solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1} dx = \int 1 + \frac 2 {e^x-1} dx = x +2\int \bigg( \frac {e^x}{e^x-1} -1 \bigg)dx$$
Now you apply your formula to evaluate last integral. You get:$$x + 2(\ln|e^x-1| - x) + c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{e^x}{e^x-1}dx = \int d(\log(e^x-1)) = \log|e^x-1|+C$$
$$\int\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}dx -\int \frac1{e^x-1}dx=\int 1dx = x + C$$
Thus $$\int \frac1{e^x-1}dx=\log|e^x-1|-x+C$$
and finally
$$ \int \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}dx = \int \frac{e^x}{e^x-1}dx + \int \frac1{e^x-1}dx= 2\log|e^x-1|-x+C $$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{-x/2}$ to form

$$\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\times\frac{e^{-x/2}}{e^{-x/2}}=\frac{e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}}{e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}}=\frac{\cosh(\frac{x}{2})}{\sinh(\frac{x}{2})},$$
then
$$\int \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\,dx=\int \frac{\cosh(\frac{x}{2})}{\sinh(\frac{x}{2})}\,dx=2\int\frac{d\left(\sinh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}{{\sinh(\frac{x}{2})}}=2\ln\left|\sinh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|+C.$$

If $K$ is a constant, then all integrals of the form $\frac{f'}{f}$ evaluate to

$$K\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx=K\ln|f(x)|+C.$$

Comment: i am not aware of what "cosh and sinh" mean. This isn't a part of my syllabus.

Comment: [Hyperbolic sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions). $$\sinh x = \frac {e^x - e^{-x}} {2}$$ $$\cosh x = \frac {e^x + e^{-x}} {2}$$

Comment: @bhuvanesh Introducing hyperbolic functions (i.e the $\cosh x$ & $\sinh x$) is the only close way of solving this without straight-forward substitution.

Also with the introduction of the imaginary number,

$$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$$
$$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$$

Comment: Also maybe for the sake of keeping it simple, we can even avoid the $\cosh$ & $\sinh x$ and use the fact that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}\right)=\left(\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}{2}\right)$$

to solve this.

Comment: @Mourad that's actually what Yves later added as his second solution (before this answer was posted). Also I would say that I avoided hyperbolic trig in my answer, and also that Yves' last point is very relevant; recognizing the form $\int f'/f$ is very close to being integration by substitution, which all of us used...

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense